# Use inferential statistics in a descriptive manner

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics

I am currently evaluating usage data from an online trainer. To answer my central question, I have determined a subsample from this data that meets certain criteria. These data can be categorized in various ways, e.g., by the part of the trainer from which they originate, or by participant characteristics.

In order to assess the balance of the data with respect to these criteria "at a glance", I would like to use inferential statistical tests such as binomial, $\chi^2$ and $t$-tests. However, it seems wrong to me (unfortunately, somehow), since at this point I do not want to infer a super-ordered, larger population from the data at hand.

Is it really wrong? Am I trying to misappropriate inferential statistical tests, or is it legitimate to use them in the "descriptive" way I would like to use them?

I hope I can clarify my question with a little more concrete illustration: The mentioned online trainer consists of 7 modules that were not necessarily worked on evenly by all participants; some participants may have used a particular module, while others may not have used it at all. Now, for example, I would like to use a $\chi^2$ test to be able to say the distribution of participants across modules is "approximately" even or not. However, this is not my central research question. I would like to use the $\chi^2$ test mentioned as an example and other inferential statistical tests only to give an overview of the composition of the data, so to speak.

Comment: After a couple of reads through this post, I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking.  Could you describe what you propose to do more specifically?

Comment: Thank you for your effort in reading and your query. I have supplemented my question with what I hope is a more concrete illustration.

Comment: Can you assess what you're interested in by clever use of graphs and tables? In your example, for sure looking at the distribution you can say whether it looks rather even. What do you get from a formal test on top of that, if you are not willing to defend the assumptions on which it is based?

Comment: I should say that I have done such things myself, so my message isn't that it should never be done, but you need to know what you're doing! It can be a hard sell and has to be motivated very carefully.

Comment: I have to admit that the primary intention behind my approach is probably to summarize. There are quite a lot perspectives from which an imbalance of the data might be apparent, so that I would like to, if you will, give an overview in the form: "A: looks okay", "B: looks not okay", ...